# How to use WP Backery on Wysiwyg ACF

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, editor

One of my client use ACF and WP Backery.
I need to use the backery editor to include a specific component, but it must apply on a wysiwyg ACF.

For the moment, I can apply the WP Backery editor only on the content wysiwyg with general settings.

How can I do this ?

Comment: WPBakery and ACF both being 3rd party software are considered off topic here.

Comment: Anyway: it might be easier to have a custom post type, this will allow you to use the page builder, and link that site via ACF relation to the other post. (If I understand you correctly)